# Raspberry Pi 2 Raspbian: OBEX FTP to phone over bluetooth

Tags: linux, ftp, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I am  trying to send a file over Bluetooth through OBEX. I have installed the obexftp package. I am able to pair the phone using `pair` in `bluetoothctl`. When I try to transfer a file with this :

```
sudo obexftp -b  00:25:48:11:32:B7 -p /home/pi/rik.txt
```

This is the output which I am getting :

```
Browsing 00:25:48:11:32:B7 ...
Connecting...failed: connect
Tried to connect for 3000ms
Interupted/bad reception or the device moved out of range: Operation now in progress
Still trying to connect
Connecting...failed: connect
Tried to connect for 0ms
error on connect(): Device or resource busy
Still trying to connect
Connecting...failed: connect
Tried to connect for 0ms
error on connect(): Device or resource busy
Still trying to connect
```

How do I go about solving this problem ?

Comment: Di you try with the parameter -channel 12?